# MongoDb: Nest one Collection's Documents in Another For Query Results

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have two MongoDb collections (with example fields):

```
People: 
_id: 2
name: 'bob'
carIds: [1,2,3]
```

and

```
Cars:
_id: 82
model: 'Camry'
```

Is there a way to return a list of `People` with a new field `Cars` which will have an array of `Cars` that have a `carId` that matches `carIds` in People.

I do NOT want to create the field permanently, just for the query results. Can I do this with map somehow? I tried:

```
var peopleWithCars = db.people.find({
}).map(function(doc) {

    var carIds = doc.carIds; 

    var cars = db.cars.find({
        _id: { $in: carIds} 
    })

    doc.cars= cars;

    return doc;
});

return peopleWithCars ;
```

And got:

> Error: Line 18: Illegal return statement

Edit - this is what finally worked:

```
db.people.find({
        }).map(function(doc) {

        var carIds = doc.carIds; 

        var cars = db.cars.find({
            _id: { $in: carIds} 
        }).toArray(); 

        doc.cars= cars;

        return doc;
    });
```

For some reason it still doesn't like vars, but this forces items to be returned, instead of a query for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find() method returns a cursor. You need to convert it to an array ( cursor.toArray () IIRC). That should solve both your problems.

```
var cars= db.find(...).toArray()
```

But to be honest, that is not the best design if you want to use this query very often. You'd better add a field 'personId' to the car and query on the cars collection with a single query.

Comment: Updating since you updated - I tried that. It still returns the same error with the first version. With the second version (without 'var cars'), it returns 'Query execute successfully, but there are not results to show'

Comment: Also do a .toArray () for the cars field.

Comment: toArray is what solved it, but for some reason it doesn't work if we run it on the people find. But it does force the cars query to execute. Ty again for help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take with a single query is by using the aggregation framework and running a pipeline that has the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator. This performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. The **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** stage does an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the "joined" collection.

The following example shows how you can apply this with your case:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$carIds" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "cars",
            localField: "carIds",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "cars"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$cars" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "cars": { "$push": "$cars" }
        }
    }
])
```